# How can I remove some characters in the current webpage link in PHP to have a link to change language?

Tags: php, character

:)

I am novice
to PHP and I am stuck on one thing. I trid to use things like  **$str1 = substr($str, 2);** but I'm not sure how to use those kind of codes.

I have a bilingual website.
The default language is French and all files are in the root folder.

The files for the English-speaking part of the site are in a directory named **en**

I want to be able to switch from one language to another, but staying on "the same page".

Example: if I'm on the French book suggestion page, I want to be able to switch to English on the book suggestion page.

To switch from French to English, I have this code (link) which works very well.

This code adds **en/** in the right place.

```
<a href="   <?php 
$url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$positionslash= strrpos($url, "/");
$filename= substr($url, $positionslash + 1);
echo "en/". $filename;
?>  " title="English" target="_self">English</a>
```

Exemple (the following links are just exemples):

We go from [www.my-domaine.com/books.php](http://www.my-domaine.com/books.php)

to arrive at [www.my-domaine.com/en/books.php](http://www.my-domaine.com/en/books.php)

To switch from English to French I would have to be able to delete the **en/**, but I can't find how.

I want to go from de [www.my-domaine.com/en/books.php](http://www.my-domaine.com/en/books.php)

to arrive at [www.my-domaine.com/en/books.php](http://www.my-domaine.com/en/books.php)

Comment: Why not remove the string containing `en/` from that output? After all, it might be easier to use some kind of routing framework for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the "language" by replacing it with an empty string.

```
str_replace("en/", "", $url)
```

Next time I would store the language in the session (cookie).

Comment: Thank you Thijs van Tol !  That works. :)

What storing the language in the session or in cookie would do ? I don't know much about sessions or cokies.